# Discord.js / finding role by ID from an array

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making role giving command for my discord.js bot.
If selected role equals to any ID's from an array, then command will work; if it not then it will return.

Here's the code I was trying:

```
    let roles = 
    [
      1024591717820813322,
      1023191063449571348,
    ]

    if (testR.id == roles)
    {
      interaction.reply({content: `worked`})
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to see if an element exists in an array. If the element exists, then it will return `true`, otherwise `false`. Your finished code would look something like this:

```js
let roles = [
  "1024591717820813322",
  "1023191063449571348",
]
if (roles.includes(testR.id)) {
    interaction.reply({ content: "Test Role id exists in roles array" })
} else {
    interaction.reply({ content: "Test Role id does not exist in roles array" })
}
```

(Note: in Discord, ids are stored in the form of strings, not numbers. I have made the changes accordingly and advise you to do the same.)